# issues with return-path in zend_mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, smtp, zend-mail

Could you please tell me why I set returnPath using zend_mail received email has to return-path headers (I view them in gmail) using smtp trasport:

```
Return-Path: <bounce@domain.com> //I think this is added by server
.....
Return-Path: bounce@domain.com //I think this is cause by returnPath
```

I set return-path like this:

```
$mailer->setReturnPath('bounce@domain.com');
```

I set transport like this:

```
$emailConfig = $this->getOption('email');                                   
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($emailConfig['server'], $emailConfig);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

If I don't set returnPath server add returnPath the same as I set From header.
Is it a bug in Zend_Mail or what? What I understand it right that server will add return-path header the same as it's use in MAIL_FROM and setReturnPath shouldn't add header menually, but only save it to use for MAIL_FROM?
It in Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp change code comment line:

```
/**
 * Sets the Return-Path header of the message
 *
 * @param  string    $email
 * @return Zend_Mail Provides fluent interface
 * @throws Zend_Mail_Exception if set multiple times
 */
public function setReturnPath($email)
{
    if ($this->_returnPath === null) {
        $email = $this->_filterEmail($email);
        $this->_returnPath = $email;

        //This line presents in Zend_Framework
        //I comment this like I get only one return-path the same as
        //set using setReturnPath method of Zend_Mail
        //$this->_storeHeader('Return-Path', $email, false);
    } else {
        /**
         * @see Zend_Mail_Exception
         */
        require_once 'Zend/Mail/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Mail_Exception('Return-Path Header set twice');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zend you can pass the necessary additional parameter to sendmail by explicitly choosing the transport:

```
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail('-fmail@example.com');
 $_mail = new Zend_Mail();
 $_mail->setDefaultTransport($tr);
```

Comment: Found this on [Mario's Blog](https://mariobrandt.de/archives/php/zend-framework-mail-bounce-because-of-return-path-540/)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$mail->addHeader('Return-path', 'email@address.com');
```

Comment: Did you write question before giving answer?

Comment: Besides addHeader is not correct way for setting standard header and will fail.

Comment: Can you tell anything about the gist of the question?